# VSCode Meaning of : ptyhost warning Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable

Tags: visual-studio-code, pty, vscode-remote-ssh

In VSCode I connect from Windows to Ubuntu via the Remote SSH extension. I can open the VSCode Terminal window for 'bash' and I get to shell in the remote server.

But this message shows in the Log for Remote Pty Host:
`[ptyhost] [warning] Shell integration cannot be enabled for executable "/bin/sh" and args ...`

The args for /bin/sh have a script for wget and fallback to curl to call :
`--header='Metadata-Flavor:Google' http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id`

While I don't normally use tmux, I can open that and get to shell as well. But the log shows the same warning:
`for executable "/usr/bin/tmux" and args undefined.`

Bottom line: bash and tmux are working but I'm curious about the warnings, as I'm struggling with other issues related to VSCode and Remote SSH.

What are these ptyhost errors?
What are they telling us?
What should we do to fix the problem being reported?
Might this affect other operations from VSCode?

Comment: I'm seeing the same warnings. I'm looking at the log file because VSCode is causing all  SSH connections to be locked out of my Rocky Linux system, and I'm trying to discover why.

These warnings are followed by several complaints that say "No ptyHost heartbeat after 6 seconds". I don't know if this is a cause or effect and I'm trying to track down the cause of all this.